# Mix letters (russian + latin) in a specific bibliographic reference on a mainly latin-font, IEEEtrans style, Latex article

Tags: pdflatex, cyrillic, bibliography, ieee, latin

I am writing a paper for a IEEE conference using IEEEtrans style. All the document is in plain english, but I have a single reference in bibliography whose title has a mix of characters from the Cyrillic and Latin  alphabet. I struggled two days to get it done while keeping the IEEEtrans style but I give up. If anyone has a straightforward idea how to add the following reference to an IEEE article while keeping the IEEEtrans on a mainly english document, please help.

I use Overleaf and a .bib file.

The reference to add is:

Доверяй, но проверяй: SFI safety for native-compiled Wasm.

Many thanks
Lucian

I tried combinations of font encodings like T2A, T2B, OT1, using \cyra \CYRB etc, fontselect, but I just can't get everything right.

It becomes even convoluted because the text in question is in the bibligraohy and not in the main text body, and the line itself has a mix of russian+latin characters.